# selenium blog website Testing

Tags: web-applications, web

How to handle "Publish Now" button? None of the element locators is helping. Tried the below snippet as well.But its clicking the "Save Draft" button.
List allElements = driver.findElements(By.className("post-save-publish"));

[A blog website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xUlM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As per code you shared there is no link assigned to that Publish Now button. So, it will not going to render anywhere.

But if you don't getting element using ClassName then you can try following solution :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Publish Now')]"))
```

Hope it will help you.